# How is render method in symfony used to pass the data to template?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, rendering

I am trying to learn symfony and was reading through The book which is on symfony site.I cannot understand the following part of the code in the section first Sample symfony application .
The BlogController returns `$this->render('Blog/list.html.php',array('posts'=>$posts));}`
so how is `array('posts=>$posts')` accessed in the view template

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller ;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
 public function listAction()
 { $posts = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->createQuery('SELECT p FROM AcmeBlogBundle:Post p')->execute();
return $this->render('Blog/list.html.php',array('posts'=>$posts));
}



<!-- app/Resources/views/Blog/list.html.php -->
<?php $view->extend('layout.html.php')?>
<?php $view['slots']->set('title','List of Posts')?>
<h1>
List of Posts
</h1>
<ul>
<?php foreach($posts as $post):?>
<li>
<a href="<?phpecho $view['router']->generate('blog_show',array('id'=>$post->getId()))?>">
<?php echo $post->getTitle()?>
</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it does is use [extract](https://secure.php.net/extract) and then an include. Something like:

```
<?php
function render($template, array $vars) {
  extract($vars);
  ob_start(); // This is for retrieving the result
              // of the template and not print it directly.
  include $template;
  $result = ob_get_clean();
}
```

You can see the real implementation in [Symfony Templating Component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Templating/PhpEngine.php#L132).